# Is there a way to make a mat-label clickable

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I am trying to make a mat-label clickable using `(click)="doSomething()"`

I have googled this issue and cant find any solution

this is an example of the html code I wish to make clickable

```
<mat-form-field class="col-md-2">
    <mat-label (click)="doSomething()"></mat-label>
</mat-form-field>
```

what I wish to accomplish is to keep the mat-label styling and when clicked make another mat-form-field display

Comment: So, you tried the code you posted, and it didn't work? If so, did you see any errors in the console?

Comment: @R.Richards no i didn't get any errors in the console, and the (click)='doSomething()" works when it is on another element such as <input (click)="doSomething()"

Comment: Put the `(click)="doSomething()"` in the `mat-form-field` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to write `<mat-label>` inside of `<mat-form-field>` then you must define at least one MatFormFieldControl like `matInput, mat-select, etc` under `<mat-form-field>`. It will not work with just `<mat-label>`.

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Both a label and a placeholder</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Simple placeholder">
</mat-form-field>
```

But If you want to just use `<mat-label>` then don't write it under `<mat-form-field>`

Here is the demo for your desired output

Click [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vdzrq3?file=src/app/form-field-label-example.html)!!

Answer (score 5):

Because default `mat-label` disable event click by css(`pointer-events: none;`). So, in your case you just need to override the style from `none` to `auto` as below:

```
.mat-form-field {
  .mat-form-field-label-wrapper {
    .mat-form-field-label {
      pointer-events: auto;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me

```
<mat-form-field>
 <mat-label style="cursor:pointer" (click)="doSomething()">
 </mat-label>
```